# How to replace values in table a according another table b in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, missing-data

Since Hive does not support update...
So i wonder how can achieve it in Hive.

For say, I have table A, and Table B, which are linked with a key named *user_id*. 
Then there are some missing values in *register_date* in table A. Those missing cases can be filled with *b_date* in table B.

So, for each *user_id*, if the *register_date* (in table A) is missing, then I want to fill it with corresponding *b_date* value in table B.

Any ideas about it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use case statement to do so : 
lets say you want to update table_a  column name user_id .

If user_id is null then you want to update with the column of table B which b_date then you can do so by firing below query :

select  case when a.user_id is null or len(trim(user_id)==0) then b.b_date else a.user_id end  as user_id from table_A  a join table_B b on a.id=b.id;

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE is available starting in [Hive 0.14 as mentioned here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Update). You have a good reason to upgrade now.

If you cannot upgrade Hive, you can create a new temp-table by joining table-A and table-B and then drop table-A and rename the temp-table to table-A.

Answer (score 0):

Go For the Update Hive 0.14.

Move the data of table A to table C.
Then Do a Join on Table B and Table C(give your Condition and Pick Accordingly).
Then Insert to table A.
Then Drop Table C.

Insert into TableC 
   Select * from Table A

Insert into TableA
   Select user_id,if(TableC.register_date IS NULL ,TableB.b_date) FROM TableB join TableC on TableB.user_id=TableC.user_id

Drop Table TableC;